# logstash custom log that has xml tags inside

Tags: logstash, grok

I have a custom log file that has plain text as well as xml tags. How do i capture these in separate fields. Here is how it looks like:
1/10/2017 4:16:35 AM : 
Error thrown is:
No Error

---

Request sent is:
SCEO415154712

---

Response received is:
SCEO4151547trueTBAfalse7169-1TBAfalse2389-1

```html
1/10/2017 4:16:35 AM : 
Error thrown is:
No Error
*************************************************************************
Request sent is:
<InventoryMgmtRequest xmlns="http://www.af.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/InventoryMgmtRequest"><ns0:MsgHeader MessageType="FIXORD" MsgDate="10.01.2017 04:16:32" SystemOfOrigin="ISCS_DE" CommunityID="SG888" xmlns:ns0="http://www.av.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/InventoryMgmtRequest"><ns0:OrderID>SCEO4151547</ns0:OrderID><ns0:ReservationID></ns0:ReservationID><ns0:CRD></ns0:CRD></ns0:MsgHeader><ns0:MsgBody xmlns:ns0="http://www.ab.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/InventoryMgmtRequest"><ns0:Product Sku="CH562EE" Qty="1" IsExpress="false" IsTangible="true" Region="EMEA" Country="DE"><ns0:ProdType></ns0:ProdType><ns0:LineItemNum>1</ns0:LineItemNum><ns0:JCID></ns0:JCID></ns0:Product><ns0:Product Sku="CH563EE" Qty="1" IsExpress="false" IsTangible="true" Region="EMEA" Country="DE"><ns0:ProdType></ns0:ProdType><ns0:LineItemNum>2</ns0:LineItemNum><ns0:JCID></ns0:JCID></ns0:Product></ns0:MsgBody></InventoryMgmtRequest>
*************************************************************************
Response received is:
<ns0:InventoryMgmtResponse xmlns:ns0="http://www.ad.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/InventoryMgmtResponse"><ns0:MsgHeader MsgDate="10.01.2017 04:16:32" MessageType="FIXORD"><ns0:OrderID>SCEO4151547</ns0:OrderID><ns0:ReservationID /><ns0:ReadyToRelease>true</ns0:ReadyToRelease></ns0:MsgHeader><ns0:MsgBody><ns0:Product SKU="CH562EE" LSPSKU="9432GFT" OutOfStock="false" FulfillmentSite="00ZF" SKUExist="true" Region="EMEA" Country="DE" IsTangible="true"><ns0:EDD>TBA</ns0:EDD><ns0:FutureUsed>false</ns0:FutureUsed><ns0:CurrentQty>7169</ns0:CurrentQty><ns0:FutureQty>-1</ns0:FutureQty></ns0:Product><ns0:Product SKU="CH563EE" LSPSKU="9432GFU" OutOfStock="false" FulfillmentSite="00ZF" SKUExist="true" Region="EMEA" Country="DE" IsTangible="true"><ns0:EDD>TBA</ns0:EDD><ns0:FutureUsed>false</ns0:FutureUsed><ns0:CurrentQty>2389</ns0:CurrentQty><ns0:FutureQty>-1</ns0:FutureQty></ns0:Product></ns0:MsgBody></ns0:InventoryMgmtResponse>
*************************************************************************
```

Also I don't want to capture the line separators (line full of **** at the end) in my grok fields.

Comment: @Rumbles can you kindly have a look at this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer here I'm afraid. Logstash and other log processing tools works line by line, each line is an event. If your events span more than one line you can use the [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) codec, which is pretty powerful, but in my experience you are better off trying to get the logs on to single lines at source, this makes it so much easier to write a pattern and get the process working reliably.

The issues you have here are many, but if, for example, one of your messages (sent via TCP) is retransmitted for some reason or simply (sent via UDP) lost, your pattern will break as part of the message that logstash is expecting is not there.

The *best* thing you can do in my opinion is to try and change the logging process to save to a file as a single line per event. Most logging tools should allow this with the right config options. Ideally, get your application to log in json format, (assuming you're processing logs to save them in elasticsearch) this would involve the lowest overhead on the logstash server to process these logs (as elasticsearch saves them in json format). All you would then need to do is pass each event/log line to the json filter and the fields are generated by the names given to it by your application.